# Having trouble adding a contact form to wordpress site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a contact form to my wordpress site, the form I am using is identical to one I have used on this non wordpress site http://drains2go.com/contact.php the only thing I hae done differently has been update the action attribute to:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/processForm.php" method="post">
```

Problem is that my when I submit the form my javascript ajax call isnt made and the action attr link is followed instead of the default state being disabled.

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url : contactForm.attr('action') + '?ajax=true',
        type : contactForm.attr('method'),
        data : contactForm.serialize(),
        success : function() {
```

Is the problem that I have set the action as the full link?

```
http://localhost/jmccplantsales/wp-content/themes/child-theme/processForm.php
```

Comment: You'll have more luck on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you capture the submit handler and stop the default action? `$("#contact-form").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // this stops default form submissions and page redirection //run your ajax after e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: yeah, ive got preventDefault in there. as i say this works perfectly on another site, just wondering if there is something different I have to do because Im using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom theme (other than the default or wordpress builtin themes like twentyelevan, twentyten etc).

1. Change

   ```
   <form id="contact-form" action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/processForm.php" method="post">
   ```
2. And try to use this one

   ```
   <form id="contact-form" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/processForm.php" method="post">
   ```